# How does the Kernel implement synchronisation techniques on file access

Tags: file-descriptors, synchronization, read, write, semaphore

I've read that the kernel implements synchronisation mechanisms when accessing files. For example, if we try and write or read to a file in the file system using `read()` or `write()` from different processes at the same time, the kernel will prevent race conditions.

How exactly is this implemented? I have used Mutexes and Semaphores when writing code before which prevents different threads or processes executing a certain part of the code at the same time.

In this case, I assume that the kernel should only implement a locking mechanism when more than one process or thread tries to read or write to the same file descriptor, not any time `read()` or `write()` is called, which could be for any file descriptor. How would this be achieved?

Comment: Under Linux, it is on the driver's responsibility to deal with possible concurrent accesses. In most case, you'll read mutex_lock and mutex_unlock surrounding drivers' write procedure.

Comment: @MC68020 What about a write procedure to a different device. I guess it shouldn't lock on every write?

Comment: @Engineer999 the inode lock takes care of that, indirectly. Note that device I/O is separate from file I/O and is handled quite differently.

Answer (score 1):

The locking rules for file systems in the Linux kernel are [described in the kernel documentation](https://docs.kernel.org//filesystems/locking.html), exhaustively but probably inscrutably if you’re not already familiar with VFS code.

Most file operations are synchronised using a lock on the inode, [`i_rwsem`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0.10/source/include/linux/fs.h#L643). This lock is not usually manipulated directly, but through [a number of locking functions](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0.10/source/include/linux/fs.h#L754). You can see them being used for example in Ext4 by searching for `inode_lock` in [`ext4/file.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0.10/source/fs/ext4/file.c).

Some operations also use a lock on `struct file`, [`f_lock`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0.10/source/include/linux/fs.h#L954); see [`llseek`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0.10/source/fs/read_write.c#L107) for example.